# How to query sqlalchemy in chunks?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

How does sqlalchemy handle buffering/chunking?

```
with open('out', 'w') as f: 
    query = table.select()
    for row in engine.execute(query): 
        output_row = make_row_string(row)
        print(output_row, file=f)
```

Reading from the [ResultProxy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) I infer (correctly?) that it's processing the rows all at once when they're all available. How can I query and process in chunks to make this job faster for a many-row query?

The two ideas I have for dealing with a many-row query are `.fetchmany(chunksize) while True`, or `itertools` chunks. What is the recommended way to get many rows from a remote database?

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid loading the entire resultset of a query by using [`stream_results`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.stream_results):

```
engine.execution_options(stream_results=True)
```

Note that streaming results probably won't make the query any faster -- it only makes it use less memory. Also note that if your output format is CSV, using [`COPY`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) is a lot faster.